# Можно ли корректно совместить Python + 1C + Pytelegrambotapi (telebot)?

Tags: python, 1с, telebot

Пишу ботов `pytelegrambotapi` и нужно интегрировать 1С в телеграм бот (с 1С никогда ранее не работал)

Совмещал ли кто-нибудь корректно 1С базы с Python, и если да - есть ли какие-то толковые курсы/ссылки по этому? Я погуглил и увидел, что в интернете практически нет данной информации.

Comment: Гвидо Ван Россум чуть чаем не захлебнулся, когда узнал, с чем хотят скрестить его язык =)

Comment: смотря что требуется, мы писали сервис на стороне 1с который отдаёт данные по http, а requests забирали на стороне питона

Comment: @D.Violet, скажите, а можно ли переносить 1С базы данных в mysql-базу и потом уже посредством `mysql.connector` собирать и вставлять данные в самой базе 1С?

Comment: @Inventor, таковы были пожелания заказчика:) Я, честно сказать, и сам не горю сильным желанием вникать в 1С))

Comment: @DenisRudnitskiy бегите, бегите и не оглядывайтесь, когда вас хотят заставить писать на 1с)

Comment: @Denis Rudnitskjy что?

Comment: @D.Violet, если я правильно понимаю - можно ли перевести файловую базу данных 1С в MYSQL? А ещё слышал, что можно перевести в самой программе 1С только на СУБД MSSQL (не уверен). И допустим, если я перевел базу в 1С в MSSQL - смогу ли я забирать данные на стороне питона?

Comment: перевести можно, но нужно смотреть целесообразность. на счёт забирать из питона смотря в БД не знаю, не пробовал